# Is it possible to display and redirect standard output in the same time in Batch script?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-file

I am trying to do

```
  call script.bat > script.log
```

But it does not display result in the console.
So currently I have to do

```
 call script.bat
 call script.bat > script.log
```

which is really inefficient.

Is there a way to both display output to the console and output it to log file?
I know one of the option is

```
call script.bat > script.log
type script.log
```

But that doesn't really work if script.bat is only one of the step in a long batch process, I would like to see the output for each step as it is being called instead of one execution of type at the end of all of the calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Option 1:

```
call "script.bat" > "script.log" | type "script.log"
```

Option 2:

**wintee** 
  http://code.google.com/p/wintee/

Answer (score 2):

If you work with the windows Power-Shell (as i assume of the windows tag) there is a cmdlet called Tee-Object.

```
help Tee-Object

NAME
    Tee-Object

SYNOPSIS
    Saves command output in a file or variable and displays it in the console.
```

Under Unix there is the programm *tee* that provides the same functionality.

Comment: only on the basic Win XP cmd for now. But thanks for letting me know about Power-Shell

Comment: In this case you could use 3rd party programms. Within the tools you find under http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ you find a native win32 port of unix *tee*.